# Saving VNC settings on pi

Tags: pi-3, ethernet, touchscreen, vnc, minecraft

I came across a slight problem in that I cannot save my screen capture settings on my Pi3 while using VNC viewer alongside my laptop and touchscreen.

As far as I can see, there is even no way to pull the window down as there is a bit cut off at top and bottom...

So, how can I save my settings?

Comment: VNC settings should be at `/root/.vnc/config.d/vncserver-x11`

Comment: @Fabian in cmd prompt it says permission denied, and in file explorer config.d is empty

Comment: You must be root/have permissons. From cli run `sudo ls -lah /root/.vnc/config.d/` and you will see the file - if it exists. https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/